# Erro de linker em biblioteca java (NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, biblioteca

Eu estou tendo problema com uma biblioteca que eu importei. O que eu fiz foi simplesmente extrair o arquivo zip da biblioteca e depois em Libraries usei o Add Jar/Folder para importar a bibliotca para o projeto. O erro que eu estou tendo é o seguinte:

```
Native code library failed to load.java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Lib_java in java.library.path
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Tentei também importar como zip mas o netbeans nem reconhece a biblioteca

Comment: Qual biblioteca?

Comment: não é uma biblioteca nativa do netbeans, é a biblioteca java que está neste site: http://biosignalsplux.com/en/software/apis

Comment: Qual é o link direto da lib?

Comment: http://biosignalsplux.com/downloads/api/PLUX_Java.zip

Comment: `The API consists of a jar file (NewBioPlux,jar) containing the API object code
and a dll with the JNI wrapper ( Java Native Interface ) called Lib_java.dll. The
dll file shall be installed in the Windows/system32 directory.` Você viu isso no manual que vem junto com jar dentro do zip?

Comment: na verdade não, é a primeira vez que tenho que importar uma biblioteca e não sei bem como fazer

Comment: Olha a instrução ai destacada no meu comentário, você precisa copiar a dll na pasta citada ai.

Comment: Isso resolveu, o problema, muito obrigado, mas agora o problema é: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform, tem algum jeito de rodar isso em modo de compatibilidade?

Comment: @RobertoJunior tenta colar a dll na pasta syswow64 tbm

Comment: Não funcionou, pelo o que eu pesquisei tem que ser compatível com a minha versão da JVM, tem como eu ter as duas instaladas?